# How to change the image of a list view item when it is clicked in Android Studio?

Tags: android, listview

In my custom listView I want to change Image when the image is clicked. But currently when I click on Image, first row image is changed not the one on which I clicked. My customAdapter is posted below:

```
public class WordAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Word>  {

private int mColorResourceId;

/**
 * Create a new {@link WordAdapter} object.
 *
 * @param context is the current context (i.e. Activity) that the adapter is being created in.
 * @param words is the list of {@link Word}s to be displayed.
 * @param colorResourceId is the resource ID for the background color for this list of words
 */
public WordAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Word> words, int colorResourceId) {
    super(context, 0, words);
    mColorResourceId = colorResourceId;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // Check if an existing view is being reused, otherwise inflate the view
    View listItemView = convertView;
    if (listItemView == null) {
        listItemView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(
                R.layout.list_item, parent, false);
    }

    // Get the {@link Word} object located at this position in the list
    Word currentWord = getItem(position);

    // Find the TextView in the list_item.xml layout with the ID miwok_text_view.
    TextView miwokTextView = (TextView) listItemView.findViewById(R.id.miwok_text_view);
    // Get the Miwok translation from the currentWord object and set this text on
    // the Miwok TextView.
    miwokTextView.setText(currentWord.getMiwokTranslation());

    // Find the TextView in the list_item.xml layout with the ID default_text_view.
    TextView defaultTextView = (TextView) listItemView.findViewById(R.id.default_text_view);
    // Get the default translation from the currentWord object and set this text on
    // the default TextView.
    defaultTextView.setText(currentWord.getDefaultTranslation());

    // Find the ImageView in the list_item.xml layout with the ID image.
    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) listItemView.findViewById(R.id.image);
    // Check if an image is provided for this word or not
    if (currentWord.hasImage()) {
        // If an image is available, display the provided image based on the resource ID
        imageView.setImageResource(currentWord.getImageResourceId());
        // Make sure the view is visible
        imageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    } else {
        // Otherwise hide the ImageView (set visibility to GONE)
        imageView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

    // Set the theme color for the list item
    View textContainer = listItemView.findViewById(R.id.text_container);
    // Find the color that the resource ID maps to
    int color = ContextCompat.getColor(getContext(), mColorResourceId);
    // Set the background color of the text container View
    textContainer.setBackgroundColor(color);

    // Return the whole list item layout (containing 2 TextViews) so that it can be shown in
    // the ListView.
    return listItemView;
}
}
```

And my onItemClickListener is as:

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long l) {
            // Release the media player if it currently exists because we are about to
            // play a different sound file
            releaseMediaPlayer();

            // Get the {@link Word} object at the given position the user clicked on
            Word word = words.get(position);

            // Create and setup the {@link MediaPlayer} for the audio resource associated
            // with the current word
            mMediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(ColorsActivity.this, word.getAudioResourceId());

            // Start the audio file
            mMediaPlayer.start();


            //To get the pause icon
            ImageView img=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image2);
            img.setImageResource(word.getPlayId());


            // Setup a listener on the media player, so that we can stop and release the
            // media player once the sound has finished playing.
            mMediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(mCompletionListener);
        }
    });
}
```

I want to change the image of imageView of id=R.id.image2 when it is clicked.
Any help will be appreciated.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to write view.findViewById and not just findViewById -

Change -

`ImageView img=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image2);`

to

`ImageView img=(ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.image2);`